# ASP.NET Core MVC - app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}") always shows status code of 0 in controller

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to implement some custom error handling logic for 404 and 500 errors. I have configured my error controller and some simple views for now, and i am trying to utilize the middleware `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute`. The issue I am facing is that when implementing it the way I see in other examples, I always receive a status code of 0 in my error controller route.

Why can is the actual http statuscode not being passed in as a parameter value to the controller?

My understanding is that I should be getting a status code of 404 as the int param in the controller method, but it is literally always 0. Am I missing something here? I have tried to look at other examples of similar issues here but cannot seem to determine what is missing.

Here is is code I am working with, using ASP.NET Core 7 MVC + ASP.NET MVC 5.

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// MVC
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(); //for debugging views
else
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

// Add services to the container.
// Blazor
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddHubOptions(options =>
    {
        options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        options.EnableDetailedErrors = false;
        options.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        options.MaximumParallelInvocationsPerClient = 1;
        options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 32 * 1024;
        options.StreamBufferCapacity = 10;
    });

//Mudblazor UI Lib
//builder.Services.AddMudServices();

//connstring configs
builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));

//EF registrations
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ArticlesContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ArticleDBconnectionString")));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ProductContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ProductsConnection")));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");    
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();    
}

//app.UseStatusCodePages();

app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
app.UseMiddleware<ViewNotFoundExceptionMiddleware>();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

//Razor config
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapBlazorHub();

//mvc config
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

ErrorController.cs

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
        
        [Route("/Error/{code}")]
        new public ActionResult NotFound(int StatusCode)
        {            
            var errorFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
            var error = errorFeature?.Error;
            ViewBag.ErrorMsg = "404 Page not found please try again XD";
            return View("Error", ViewBag);
        }

        [Route("/Error")]
        public ActionResult Error(int StatusCode)
        {
            var errorFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
            var error = errorFeature?.Error;
            ViewBag.ErrorMsg = "500 Server Error please try again XD";
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps change the route to `[Route("/Error/{StatusCode}")]` to match the parameter name.

Comment: wow you were 100% correct thank you I cant believe i overlooked that. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the route with the `statusCode` parameter instead of `code`. While you should name the variable with camel case to follow the C# naming conventions.

```cs
[Route("/Error/{statusCode}")]
public ActionResult NotFound(int statusCode)
```